# Firestore non exisitng document Id

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I'm using [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore) for a Xamarin.Forms project.

I'm calling:

```
CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                   .Instance
                   .Collection("myCollection")
                   .Document("nonExistentId")
                   .GetAsync()
                   .Id;
```

for a non existent Firestore document. It returns an `int` of a value of `1`.

Is `1` a standard value (defined either in Firestore's documentation or in this specific Xamarin plugin) that signifies a non existent document?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `await` the result of `GetAsync` in order to get an actual document snapshot?  That's what all the examples on GitHub are showing.  None of the examples are trying to reference a document field without `await`.

Comment: If I use await in my code mentioned above I get this error: `Error CS1061 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: The `await` needs to be on the `GetAsync()`, not on the call to `Id`. You'll need to add some parenthesis to fix that.

Comment: OK, I fixed it. Adding `await` now returns as a result the `nonExistentId` I pass as an argument in `Document("nonExistentId")`, even though such a document doesn't exist in the database.

Anyway, I found out that the plugin has a field called `Exists` for checking for document existence, which I has previously missed, so I will use that for my purpose.

Comment: @Costas Glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that **Plugin.CloudFirestore** has a field called Exists for checking for the existence of documents in Firestore database.

The code can be changed as follows:

```
var document = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
               .Instance
               .Collection("myCollection")
               .Document("nonExistentId")
               .GetAsync()
               .Id;

if (document.Exists == false) //or true
{
    // Do whatever you wish
}
```